# How to split large dataset to chunks and perform fit_transform / fit_resample and union result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am dealing with highly imbalanced and large dataset. I am trying to imblearn

```
smote_nc = SMOTENC(categorical_features=[df.dtypes=='category'], random_state=0)
X, y = smote_nc.fit_resample(X,y)
```

But fell into MemoryError

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.2 GiB for an array with shape (190824, 10724) and data type float64
```

Is there any way to chunk this operation and save the balanced result to dataframe?

The dataset example looks like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

Smote is an oversampling method. It generates new, additional training samples that will help you to overcome the imbalance of the original data set. This method creates a very big dataset that does not fit into memory. One thing you could try is to specify the [sampling strategy](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) keyword. For example, for binary classification you can set a ratio of 0.3. The output dataset should be smaller and hence fit into memory.

Note that I have not tested it. It is just a suggestion. If that's not an option for you feel free to paste some sample data so we can have look.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Unfortunately, ratio of 0.3 leads to error The specified ratio required to remove samples from the minority class while trying to generate new samples. Please increase the ratio. I added some dataframe example